# Google Chrome didn't add apt source list

Tags: apt, google-chrome, 16.10

So I just installed the latest Chrome in my new Ubuntu 16.10 installation. But I just checked the "additional software" source list but I couldn't find the entry for Google Chrome that it normally creates. So at this point, Google Chrome won't be auto-updated.

Is there someone who can give me the correct source list entry for the stable channel of Google Chrome? Or what can I do to make the Google deb add it automatically again?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have this file `/etc/default/google-chrome`

Comment: Yup, it's there.. but it's not in my apt list

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From Google chrome download page:

> **Note:** Installing Google Chrome will **add the Google repository** so your
>   system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date. If you don’t
>   want Google's repository, do “`sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome`”
>   before installing the package.

So to fix it:

1. Remove that file

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/default/google-chrome
   ```
2. Reconfigure chrome package to add repository

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure google-chrome-stable
   ```

   Check using `grep -r google /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, no output then reinstall it.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -r google-chrome-stable
   sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_*.deb
   ```

Otherwise add it manually

**64bit:**

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

**32bit:**

```
echo "deb [arch=i386] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But that didn't seem to work :( When I open "software & updates" and look in the "additional software" tab it still isn't listed there.

Comment: @Gladen, Check `grep -r google /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` , not in *addition software* tab but should be in *other software* tab.

Comment: Nope, also doesn't return anything :( Sorry, I am translating it from Dutch so the names I wrote may not be like they are in English :p

Comment: @Gladen, updated my answer

Comment: I used the manual method and that seems to work for now.. looks like the deb is bugged in some way or something.. At least thanks for all the support! :)

Answer (score 1):

The bug report for this can be found at https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=663069 and the cause is:

> In prior versions of Ubuntu/Debian the Dir::Etc apt-config variable
>   contained a trailing slash by default. The cronjob at
>   /etc/cron.daily/google-chrome was concatenating that variable into a
>   path, assuming the trailing slash. But in Ubuntu 16.10, the trailing
>   slash is gone. That breaks the path to the list file, and the cronjob
>   fails to fix it.

This bug has been fixed since November 8. To fix the problem, you can simply download Google Chrome again from https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html and reinstall it using `dpkg`. In my case, since I am using Google Chrome on the dev channel, I run:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-unstable_current_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome fails to install entry in /sources.list.d/ after install / upgrade to 16.10.

SEE:  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660145

AND:  https://github.com/keybase/client/commit/7894c1f57f3ca5ecb3b5fc87e4496769103b7fd4

for possible *** WORK-AROUNDS *** till fixed by upstream.

Comment: please could you add any suitable tested workarounds to your answer?

Comment: @Zanna The workaround that worked for me was to just add the right item manually. See the accepted answer for details.